# MySql query - finding articles by distinct author order by id desc

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `article table` where I want to fetch latest 3 articles but the author should be unique.

My table structure is:

```
article table
id | author_id
1  |    1   
2  |    1   
3  |    2   
4  |    4   
5  |    4   
6  |    5   
7  |    5
```

Expected output: `article id => 7 ,5, 3`

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), id
FROM articles 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM articles 
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9eb52/1)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you please tell me how can I improve my query skills?

Comment: @D555 You can learn a lot by participating in Stack Overflow. Try to answer some of the questions posted and see how other users tried to tackle each problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select max(id) from article group by author_id order by id desc  limit 3;
```

The answer will be like

```
mysql> select max(id) from article group by author_id order by id desc  limit 3;
+---------+
| max(id) |
+---------+
|       7 |
|       5 |
|       3 |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Expected output is article `id` not `author_id`. Also there is no point grouping by `author_id` and using `distinct author_id` at the same time.

Comment: It is still wrong. You have to sort by `MAX(id)`. But then your query would be equivalent to the one of the other answer.